# Apache 2.2.14 / mod_auth_kerb 5.4 : Custom krb5.conf for Apache Instance

Tags: apache-2.2, kerberos, environment-variables

**Objective:** Use Apache/mod_auth_kerb using a custom krb5.conf file, not system standard `/etc/krb5.conf`.

**Issue:** I've got a strongly regimented environment where we application owners are able to configure apache instances within their assigned directories, but the baseline configuration (OS and Apache core) are maintained by a separate group. As such, any changes I make to core config such as `/etc/krb5.conf` will mean replicating change to thousands of servers (risk+) or scripting a custom system configuration for this server (risk+,$+).

**Model for success:** In order to invoke `kinit` to test or `ktutil` to generate keytab files for use by Apache in this environment, overloading the `KRB5_CONFIG` environmental variable (discussed in [StackOverflow:pass kinit a custom krb5.conf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306330/))

**Question:** Is there anyway to specify either the `KRB5_CONFIG` environmental variable for Apache or force mod_auth_kerb to use another configuration?

**Failed Attempts:** I've tried running the same `env` command on the apachectl restart. Apache Directive SetEnv was overlooked as it applies to script execution based on user requests, not to Apache 'backoffice' functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On most systems there is also an `/etc/init.d/httpd` that does the original startup of the apache server. I think your only solution is to set an environmental variable in that script and use something like

```
/sbin/service httpd restart
```

to restart apache with the new environmental variables. You have to modify the environment of the process that starts httpd somehow.

Comment: I think it's a great answer, given the ridiculous constraints. I don't think it meets the objective as it requires a modification of the base  /etc, but I think you've shown yet another way for it to "not work". But given my research and your answer, I'm willing to put this to bed as "unsolvable" or "bad question".

Comment: Our final solution was to get the admins to to back down and let us have our custom kerberos config. But at least we came with reason in our pockets.

Answer (score 1):

on Red Hat systems I think `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` is the better place for env vars.

Comment: This is the better answer for most people. You should avoid modifying the init scripts, as shown in the other answer, as they may be replaced whenever updates are installed. (The OP's constraints were just absurd.)